# Integrating Autogen with Gemini Pro's APi

Tags: autogen

with the release of Gemini pro model they are offering free API for token usage , but within some limit, My question is can we integrate Autogen library with New Gemini pro api

I am trying to connect with autogen somehow i am getting error of api incorrect ,use openai api, i have my config list as

config_list = [
{
'model': 'gemini-pro',
'api_key': '',
},

]

Comment: I think it is supported, I saw a PR that seemed to have passed the tests: https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/actions/runs/7207098870/job/19633255941

And they have a branch for gemini separately:
https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/tree/gemini

@Zaid Siddiqui do let me know if you are able to get it working as I am also working on a very similar project leveraging gemini api along with autogen

Comment: @ShubhamGarg I have tried multiple times, but it gives out an error: "The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable." I am using GPT4 as of now for my project

Comment: Have you tried changing the base_url also? Here's a code that allows you to integrate mistral's API in autogen:

config_list = [
{
"base_url": "https://api.mistral.ai/v1/",
"api_key": "YOUR-MISTRAL-KEY-HERE",
"model":"mistral-medium"
}
]

llm_config = {
"config_list": config_list,
"seed": 42,
"temperature": 0.7,
"max_tokens": 8192,
}

Comment: Just going through a few draft PRs, and it seems like setting api_type = "google" might work. https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/pull/979/files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this notebook: https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/blob/7265ef1a3fb194e1d3d7345e47e4dc9a30ecd6fd/notebook/agentchat_gemini.ipynb

It is using Gemini for the basic agents (AssistantAgent) but OpenAI's API for the UserProxyAgent that acts as a user on your behalf and is able to execute the code generated by other agents. This should allow you to use autogen at a much lower cost though. I tried to modify the UserProxyAgent to use only Gemini but it didn't work. There are a few good youtube tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYieKkR_x44) that tell how to use open source models locally as well (if you have enough VRAM to load the model locally).

Kindly let me know if anyone is able to use it entirely with the Gemini's API Key without any local models or any other paid API. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Git Repo Autogen team still working on it to integrate:
https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/actions/runs/7206902638/job/19632649657

Comment: Yeah thanks for the info, I was under the impression we can integrate with any LLM,:)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hi guys, I have right answer from Shubham, Seems like they have finally integrated with geminin